# UnauthorizedAccessException when running desktop application from shared folder

Tags: .net, windows-vista, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I created a desktop application using VS 2008.

When I run it locally, all works well.

I shared my output folder (WITHOUT allowing network users to change my files) 
and ran my exe from another Vista computer on our intranet.

When running the shared exe, I receive "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" when trying to read a file.

How can I give permission to allow reading the file?
Should I change the code?
Should I grant permission to the application\folder on the Vista computer? how?

Notes:

- I do not use ClickOnce. the application should be distributed using xcopy.
- My application target framework is ".Net Framework 2.0"
- On the Vista computer, "controlPanel | UninstallOrChangePrograms" it says it has "Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1"
- I also tried to map the folder drive, but got the same errors, only now the fileName is "T:\my.ocx"

  ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ' my code:

  Dim src As String = mcGlobals.cmcFiles.mcGetFileNameOcx()
  Dim ioStream As New System.IO.FileStream(src, IO.FileMode.Open)

  ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  Public Shared Function mcGetFileNameOcx() As String

  ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ```
    Dim dirName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\"
    Dim sFiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirName, "*.ocx")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(sFiles)
      Debug.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(sFiles(i)))
      ' if found any - return the first:
      Return System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(sFiles(i))
    Next
    Return "" 

  End Function
  ```

  ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ' The Exception I receive:

  ```
  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\computerName\sharedFolderName\my.ocx' is denied.
    at System.IO._Error(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(...)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(...)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
  ```

  ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it.

According to MSDN, [FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode) ]

. . . For constructors without a FileAccess  parameter,

- if the mode parameter is set to **Append**, **Write**  is the default access.
- Otherwise, the access is set to **ReadWrite**.

-> my code used the default, with ioStream.CanWrite:=True, and I do not have **Write** permission on the shared folder.

so I added **FileAccess** parameter:

```
new code:
Dim ioStream As New System.IO.FileStream(srcOcx, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read) 

old code:
Dim ioStream As New System.IO.FileStream(srcOcx, IO.FileMode.Open)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with **.NET Framework 3.5 SP1** you are allowed to run an application from a network share. You don't have to target it, you just have to have it installed.

### References

- [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Allows managed code to be launched from a network share!](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx)
- [Run a .NET program from a mapped drive or shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359978/run-a-net-program-from-a-mapped-drive-or-shared-folder)